# Django / Pandas - Create Excel file and serve as download

Tags: python, django, pandas, export-to-excel

I am trying to create an Excel file using pandas and serving it to the user as a downloadable file via Django. I put together some different answers on the topic that I found on here and ended up with this code:

```
        collection = [{"title": "something", "price": 34, "quantity": 23}, {..}]

        output = BytesIO()

        df = pd.DataFrame(collection, columns=['title', 'price', 'quantity'])

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()

        output.seek(0)
        workbook = output.getvalue()

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(workbook, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={output_name}.xlsx'
        return response
```

It all works well until I try to open the resulting file - I can an error saying that the file is damaged or that there is something wrong with the data-format. I suspect that it could have something to do with the data being binary? How can I resolve this issue?

**SOLUTION**

Turns out I had to remove some stuff so the code looks like this now and works fine:

```
        collection = [{"title": "something", "price": 34, "quantity": 23}, {..}]

        output = BytesIO()

        df = pd.DataFrame(collection, columns=['title', 'price', 'quantity'])

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()

        output.seek(0)
        # workbook = output.getvalue()

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={output_name}.xlsx'
        return response
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you might be making that a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Below works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.xlsx"'                                        
df.to_excel(response)
return response
```

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

Turns out I had to remove some stuff so the code looks like this now and works fine:

```
        collection = [{"title": "something", "price": 34, "quantity": 23}, {..}]

        output = BytesIO()

        df = pd.DataFrame(collection, columns=['title', 'price', 'quantity'])

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()

        output.seek(0)
        # workbook = output.getvalue()

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={output_name}.xlsx'
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a datatype issue when opening in Excel, try converting the data into strings and then create excel and try.

Another thought is to create file with a sample set of records, rather than whole frame to validate if its a data issue. There might be an issue with Nan's in the dataset as well. Check if you need to ignore/convert/replace that.

Answer (score 0):

suggested by AI :):

```
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="my_data.xlsx"'
df.to_excel(response, index=False)
return response
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).